# Possible to use only one package version using pnpm?

Tags: npm, graphql, dependencies, apollo-server, pnpm

I need to use `apollo-server` and `graphql-upload` to handle file uploads. This is working as expected with the old graphql-upload v9. Updating to the latest v11 results in failing uploads. To make it short, the problem is, that `apollo-server` (and `@nestjs/graphql`) are depending on the old `graphql-upload` v8. ([For those, who are interested in more](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-upload/issues/185#issuecomment-583572804)) To get everything working, there should only be one version (v11) in my project.

I'm using **pnpm**. Listing which packages are using `graphql-upload` I get following:

```
@nestjs/graphql 7.9.1
├─┬ @apollo/gateway 0.17.0
│ └─┬ apollo-server-core 2.19.0
│   └── graphql-upload 8.1.0      // <--
├─┬ apollo-server-core 2.16.1
│ └── graphql-upload 8.1.0        // <--
└─┬ apollo-server-testing 2.19.0
  └─┬ apollo-server-core 2.19.0
    └── graphql-upload 8.1.0      // <--
apollo-server 2.19.0
├─┬ apollo-server-core 2.19.0
│ └── graphql-upload 8.1.0        // <--
└─┬ apollo-server-express 2.19.0
  └─┬ apollo-server-core 2.19.0
    └── graphql-upload 8.1.0      // <--
graphql-upload 9.0.0              // <-- only working if <v10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use [pnpm overrides](https://pnpm.io/package_json#pnpmoverrides). In your case, you would add this to your `package.json`:

```json
{
  "pnpm": {
    "overrides": {
      "graphql-upload": "11"
    }
  }
}
```

After adding or changing these overrides, just run `pnpm install` and pnpm will update your node_modules accordingly.

Comment: That link is broken.

Comment: fixed. The domain changed to pnpm.io from pnpm.js.org